# Reshape a Dataframe with Pandas

Tags: pivot, pandas, reshape

How can I reshape this dataframe with Pandas

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3     | value  
-----------------------------------
1  | A1   | B1   | before   | 20     
2  | A1   | B1   | after    | 13
3  | A1   | B2   | before   | 11
4  | A1   | B2   | after    | 21
5  | A2   | B1   | before   | 18 
6  | A2   | B1   | after    | 22
```

... into the following format?

```
col1 | col2 | before  | after
-------------------------------
A1   | B1   | 20      | 13
A1   | B2   | 11      | 21
A1   | B1   | 18      | 22
```

EDIT: A1 in the last line of the second table is supposed to be A2.

As the data is paired (e.g. "before" and "after") I need the columns to be aligned without 'NAs'.

```
df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col3', values='value')
```

does not work because `col1` does not result in an unique index. I could create an additional column which would result in being unique. Is that the only way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want col1 and col2 to look like after you pivot?  Your example output shows A1 and B1 for the final row yet neither of those values are associated with the 18 and 22. I have a couple of options:

```
In [234]: tmp = DataFrame(
    {'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 
     'col1':['A1','A1','A1','A1','A2','A2'],
     'col2':['B1','B1','B2','B2','B1','B2'],
     'col3':['before','after','before','after','before','after'],
     'value':[20,13,11,21,18,22]},
    columns=['id','col1','col2','col3','value'])
```

Option 1:

```
In [236]: pivoted = pd.pivot_table(tmp, values='value',
                                        rows=['col1','col2'],
                                        cols=['col3'])
In [237]: pivoted
Out[237]:
col3       after  before
col1 col2
A1   B1       13      20
     B2       21      11
A2   B1      NaN      18
     B2       22     NaN
```

This doesn't sound like the kind of behavior you want.

Option 2:

```
In [238]: pivoted = pivoted.fillna(method='bfill').dropna()
Out[238]:
col3       after  before
col1 col2
A1   B1       13      20
     B2       21      11
A2   B1       22      18

In [245]: pivoted.reset_index()
Out[245]:
col3 col1 col2  after  before
0      A1   B1     13      20
1      A1   B2     21      11
2      A2   B1     22      18
```

This gets you pretty close.  Again, I'm not sure how you want col1 and col2 to behave, but this has the right values in the before and after columns.

Comment: There was a mistake in my question. I left a comment in my question. Your first option provided the correct solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by your matrix data col1 cannot be an index because, as you said, it "does not result in an unique index".

I think your best best is:

```
grouped = df.groupby('col3')
pandas.merge(grouped.first(), grouped.last(), on=['col1','col2'])
```